# How to handle json in angular4

Tags: json, angular

**When I work with a partner to write a website, the backend returns the json format as follows. My front end uses angular4 but I don't know how to use angular4 to process the following json format data. It is a bit worse and there is no json.parse method.**

`{
    "pageNum":1,
    "pageSize":4,
    "size":1,
    "startRow":1,
    "endRow":1,
    "total":1,
    "pages":1,
    "list":[
        {
            "owner":"aa",
            "zh_name":"武世伟：广佛06.19-24搭乘ID（正确）",
            "push_status":1,
            "business":1,
            "create_time":1514256602000,
            "coupon_status":1,
            "monitor_status":1,
            "model_status":3,
            "message_status":1,
            "monitor_end_time":1514256602000,
            "random_group":1,
            "name":"p_pm_passenger_taxi_20171226105028119",
            "calc_way":1,
            "monitor_start_time":1514256602000,
            "id":11,
            "model_num":8837
        }
    ],
    "prePage":0,
    "nextPage":0,
    "isFirstPage":true,
    "isLastPage":true,
    "hasPreviousPage":false,
    "hasNextPage":false,
    "navigatePages":8,
    "navigatepageNums":[
        1
    ],
    "navigateFirstPage":1,
    "navigateLastPage":1,
    "status":200,//状态200正常，400 错误
    "firstPage":1,
    "lastPage":1
}`

Comment: What do you want to do with the json? What is the expected output? And add some code. So we can know what have you done so far

Comment: Read the documentation beforeall. Here's how to handle json data with Http: https://angular.io/guide/http#!#sts=Parse%20to%20JSON

Answer (score 0):

Angular indeed provides you with a JSON.parse()-method which actually derives from JavaScript. You can convert your server response json into an object.

```
// in your component
private object;
```

Then you can access the content. For example:

```
// call this method after having received your json
private show(data: any): void {
    this.object = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(this.object.pageNum);
    console.log(this.object.total);
    console.log(this.object.list[0].zh_name);
}
```